# Error in android apk using Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client

Tags: android, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

I've got project which is using Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client SDK. When I run it in Emulator from VS everything is good. But when I am building apk at TC server and install it on real android device - I got following error: `VTable setup of type Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileService.Eventing.MobileServiceEventManager failed`. How I could fix that? I am using Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client package v 3.1.0.
I am buildin apk using following command:
`xbuild /t:SignAndroidPackage /p:Configuration=Release /p:AndroidSdkDirectory=/Users/administrator/Library/Android/sdk GoBounce/Droid/GoBounce.Droid.csproj`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem that target framework was Android 5. When I've changed it to latest(android 7) - everything worked fine.